# In which episode does this picture from the opening of K-ON! appear?

Tags: k-on

In the first opening of K-ON!, the following appears at 35 seconds.

[image: k-on!]

Which episode is that picture with Ritsu in the green clothing from? And what is the time mark in the episode?

Comment: Generally speaking, the pictures appearing in the background of those scenes in the opening are not necessarily from the episodes.

Comment: @Pteromys If it's in fact not from an episode, then that would be an acceptable answer too.

Comment: I currently don't have access to the whole episodes, but here's my guess: those pictures are usually from the original comic books, and Ritsu's picture in question appears in an episodes in the book which didn't appeared in the anime series, and hence the picture itself didn't appeared in anime series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the scenes from the K-On openings don't ever happen in the anime or manga. They're things that we can imagine might have happened off camera sometime. I'm fairly certain this scene of Ritsu is one of those.

For example, this image of Mio wearing Nodoka's glasses never happens:

[image: mio in glasses]

And Azusa never licks the whisk like this:

[image: azusa licking whisk]

Clannad does the same thing—the opening contains scenes that look like they're repeated from somewhere in the series, but actually aren't, like this one:

[image: kotomi blowing dandelion]

And this one:

[image: kyou and tomoya]

It's obviously difficult to present hard proof for this, especially hard proof that that specific scene with Ritsu never appears, but I'm 99% certain that those two scenes I mentioned with Mio and Azusa never appeared anywhere. I'm about 85% certain the scene with Ritsu never happened in the anime, and about 75% certain it was never in the manga. However, there might have been a similar or related scene; Azusa did make a cake, so we can imagine she might have licked the whisk while doing that, and this might be a similar case.